# DYNAMIC UNION TABLES

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to Create a Dynamic Table where I don't Have to update the Table name each and every month. since i am working with the same query (no changes but the table name in the form (dbo.tablename_201705) to (dbo.tablename_201706) and so on. so i created this

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(20) 
SET @TABLE_NAME ='dbo.GTI_'+left (convert(varchar,dateadd(mm,-3, getdate()-7), 112) ,6)

DECLARE @GTI_SQL_REPORT VARCHAR(255) 
SET @GTI_SQL_REPORT = 'select*from '+@TABLE_NAME.
```

And from here I am lost I don't know the next step
and here below is my query

```
Select 
   [CountryID], 
   COUNT([Document name]) as [inputcount], 
   MONTH([Creation Date]) AS [Creation Month], 
   Year([Creation Date]) as [Creation Year]
from 
   dbo.GTI_201705 
WHERE  
   [doc_type_product_type] not in ('CUST')
   and [Document_Source] in ('FAX','Original')  
group by 
   [CountryID],
   MONTH([Creation Date]) ,
   Year([Creation Date]) 
order by 
   [CountryID];
```

so the idea is to create a dynamic table so that this query will run at the beginning of each month. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You were close... You just need to set the `@GTI_SQL_REPORT` to `varchar(max)` and then set the query to it. `varchar(255)` wouldn't be enough to hold your dynamic string. Notice the `print(@GTI_SQL_REPORT)` at the bottm. It's wise to do this first, so you will see what SQL you are executing. Once you are satisfied... then just comment it out and uncomment out the `EXEC` command.

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(20) 
SET @TABLE_NAME ='dbo.GTI_'+left (convert(varchar,dateadd(mm,-3, getdate()-7), 112) ,6)

DECLARE @GTI_SQL_REPORT VARCHAR(max) 
SET @GTI_SQL_REPORT = 
    'Select 
       [CountryID], 
       COUNT([Document name]) as [inputcount], 
       MONTH([Creation Date]) AS [Creation Month], 
       Year([Creation Date]) as [Creation Year]
    from ' + @TABLE_NAME + '
    WHERE  
       [doc_type_product_type] not in (''CUST'')
       and [Document_Source] in (''FAX'',''Original'')  
    group by 
       [CountryID],
       MONTH([Creation Date]) ,
       Year([Creation Date]) 
    order by 
   [CountryID]; '

print(@GTI_SQL_REPORT)
--exec(@GTI_SQL_REPORT)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... have a nice day

Comment: Thank you very much yes it did, but i have a question in case i want to report  more than a period . like reporting for dbo.GTI_201704,GTI_201705 and GTI_201706 TO SEE THE TREND IN THE SAME REPORT LIKE CUMULATIVE  REPORT.

Comment: @issamozeir that should be opened as a new question after you accept this one (since it answered the original question) as it will gain more visibility from the community (from users other than myself)